# Integer to byte array Little Endian and vice versa

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want methods to convert integer to byte array (little endian),
and from byte array (encoded in little endian way) to integer in C; 
regardless if we work on LE or BE machine.

Are these functions fine for this?

```
void Int2ByteArrayLE(int x,unsigned char *byteArray)
{

  byteArray[0]=x;
  byteArray[1]=x>>8;
  byteArray[2]=x>>16;
  byteArray[3]=x>>24;
}


void ByteArrayLE2Int(unsigned char *byteArray, int*x)
{
  *x=byteArray[0] | (byteArray[1]<<8) | (byteArray[2]<<16) | (byteArray[3]<<24);
}
```

**PS. Does this also work if x is signed?**

Comment: @harold: As far as I know when you cast integer to unsigned char, most significant bits are dropped(when int is larger than unsigned char)-is this what you mean?

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing this? I suspect that there's a better solution available.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I think it is common isn't it? Especially if you want to send integer over network when server expects the integer in little endian format for example

Comment: So you are doing it wrong in that case! Don't attempt to convert from little endian to big endian. Convert from host byte order to network byte order. Using the well known functions from your sockets library.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I believe he was thinking about negative values.

Comment: @harold That's perfectly fine and defined behavior. Unsigned arithmetic is defined in terms of modulo 2 to the `CHAR_BIT` power, so `(unsigned char)(int)-1` is `(unsigned char)((1 << CHAR_BIT) - 1)`, most commonly 255, if `char` is 8 bits wide. Also, there's no such thing as an "implicit cast". A cast is explicit by its very definition. Better call this "implicit conversion".

Comment: I think I should use `memcpy`. My machine is little endian and server also expects numbers in little endian

Comment: Curious that the code it targeted for LE and BE machines, but pays _no_ regard to the _size_ of `int` like 2 or 8.

Comment: @chux: I think I will go for the memcpy approach as my machine is also LE

Comment: If you use your `byteArray[0]=x; ... byteArray[3]=x>>24;` or `memcpy()`, it is possible they result in the same code with a smart compiler on a LE machine.  But your `byteArray[0]=x;...` has the advantage that it does not depend on `int` endian-ness.  IMO, your code is almost fine as it is expect I'd use `int32_t x` rather than `int x`.  2nd function suggestion: `void ByteArrayLE2Int(unsigned char *byteArray, int32_t x*x) { *x=byteArray[0] | ((int32_t x)byteArray[1]<<8) | ((int32_t x)byteArray[2]<<16) | ((int32_t x)byteArray[3]<<24); }`

Comment: @chux: Thank you for your suggestion. I am not sure how people serialize negative integers into byte array though still (out of curiosity, maybe I won't even need negative integers)

Comment: IMO, your code works fine for `unsigned` and `signed` integers.

Answer (score 2):

What you are actually trying to do is convert between host byte order and network byte order. And what you need for that are the functions `htonl` and `ntohl`.

To convert from host to network byte order you use:

```
uint32_t n = (uint32_t)htonl((uint32_t)h);
```

And in the opposite direction:

```
int h = (int)ntohl((uint32_t)n);
```

These functions are aware of the endianness of the host platform. So if you execute the code on a big endian machine, these functions do nothing. But on a little endian machine the functions reverse the bytes.

In the comments you intimate that your communication protocol requires information to be passed in little endian byte order. This is surely a mistake. You should follow the standard protocol and transmit data on the wire in network byte order.

If you really cannot change the protocol, and that expects little endian over the wire, then you simply need a `memcpy`. Your values are already little endian and clearly reversing the bytes won't help.

If you find yourself on a big endian client then of course you now do need to reverse the bytes. Use this function for that:

```
uint32_t reverseBytes32(uint32_t v){
  return ((v & 0xFF) << 24) | ((v & 0xFF00) << 8) 
         | ((v & 0xFF0000) >> 8) | ((v & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
}
```

You'll need to use casts to reinterpret your signed `int` as an unsigned `uint32_t`.

Comment: David no, the server expects byte array (representing int) in little endian order

Comment: Ok if my machine is also little endian, and I want to send negative value over socket, and I just to `memcpy` of integer to byte array is it OK? (given server expects little endian integer)

Comment: I think you need to fix your communication protocols and start using network byte order.

Comment: I have no control over server

Comment: It beggars belief that somebody designed a client/server system and used little endian byte order. Shame on that person!

Comment: Well I have specification of server protocol and for example it says, first two bytes it expects packet size - and then in parentheses it has written "Little Endian" - so my assumption is correct that it expects little endian right?

Comment: You should ask that question to someone with knowledge of the protocol, perhaps the vendor

Comment: `memcpy` works on negative numbers also right? (ps. out of curiosity: how are negative numbers serialized to byte arrays then?)

Comment: Yes `memcpy` works on negative numbers. When you `memcpy` onto a byte array you get the constituent bytes of your, presumably, two's complement representation of the integer.

Comment: Is network endian guaranteed to be Big Endian?  I thought the [network endian-ness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_networking) depended on the network.

Comment: @chux It's the protocol that determines it. I would be surprised if we were not talking about TCP/IP here.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a few problems:

- On a system with 16 bit `int`, the code will not work.
- In 99% of the cases, it doesn't make any sense what-so-ever to use bitwise operators on signed integers. In case the signed integers contain negative numbers, you will even encounter undefined behavior if you left shift.

So the code is generally non-portable. You need to change the code to the following:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void uint32_to_ByteArrayLE (uint32_t x, uint8_t* byteArray)
{
  // explicit casts will prevent implicit conversion warnings:
  byteArray[0] = (uint8_t)(x >>  0);
  byteArray[1] = (uint8_t)(x >>  8);
  byteArray[2] = (uint8_t)(x >> 16);
  byteArray[3] = (uint8_t)(x >> 24);
}


void ByteArrayLE_to_uint32 (const uint8_t* byteArray, uint32_t* x)
{
  /* casts -before- shifting are necessary to prevent integer promotion 
     and to make the code portable no matter integer size: */

  *x = (uint32_t)byteArray[0] <<  0 | 
       (uint32_t)byteArray[1] <<  8 | 
       (uint32_t)byteArray[2] << 16 | 
       (uint32_t)byteArray[3] << 24;
}
```

If not for the casts in the second function, the shift would occur on an `int`, which is not what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, but how people write similar functions for negative numbers? e.g., when x is negative?

Comment: @dmcr_code In the same way just cast to uint32_t first, then cast back to a signed number.

Comment: So you mean I cast `x` to `uint32_t` **before** I feed it to `uint32_to_ByteArrayLE` function? And then I cast also `x` returned from `ByteArrayLE_to_uint32`  to `int`?

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the standard (5.8 Shift operators):

"E1 << E2 ... if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1 * 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

"The value of E1 >> E2 s E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. ... If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined."

So, when x is signed and negative, the behavior is undefined for << and implementation-defined for >>. Generally, for signed x the code will work if only x is non-negative.

Comment: In the former case, behavior will be undefined only for values that don't fit in the target type.

Answer (score 0):

ya. it will work same on signed integers too since this code is independent of sign bit extension at MSB by >> shift. i.e. whether sign bit is implented or not it is not going to affect the code since it involves handling only the 32 bits of X as it is.  just store and retrive 32 bits. so the bits added by >> at MSB will not be considered. To understand consider,
if x is `int x;`   //i.e. signed integer then

x=-1 i.e 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111

byteArray[0]=x;    11111111 11111111 11111111 `11111111`
  byteArray[1]=x>>8;    xxxxxxxx 11111111 11111111 `11111111`
  byteArray[2]=x>>16;   xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx 11111111 `11111111`
  byteArray[3]=x>>24;   xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx `11111111`

The bits added by >> `xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx` are not stored/used so they will not affect the code.
so the sign bit extension is `done or not` by shift operator will not effect the code as it is clear from above example that the bits inserted by shift `x` are not used to store. therefore code can successfully store the number as it is in binartarray and can be retrived back to `int x`